# How to get the current View in RenderController on Android backbutton event

Tags: famo.us

How can we handle back button press in android, as of now I am catching backButtonPress event with following code :

> document.addEventListener("backbutton", function({
>        document.location.reload(true);
>    },false);

I am trying improve this implementation by pushing renderController and the current view it is showing to the array and popping them on press of a back button. But the problem here is, I am not able to get current view that render controller is showing.

**Is there any way we can get the current render node the RenderController is showing?**

**Is their any other way I can handle android back button press event?**

Comment: Are you using cordova?

Comment: Hi talves, sorry I should have mentioned that, yes I am using cordova 4.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to get the current renderable from the `RenderController`

You could keep track of the renderable you passed using the `show` method.

#### OR

You could extend the `RenderController`

```js
  var RenderController = require("famous/views/RenderController");
  RenderController.prototype.getRenderNode = function getRenderNode() {
    return this._renderables[this._showing];
  }
```

Later you can call the method and get the render node passed with the `show` method.

```js
var node = renderController.getRenderNode();
```